# How to modify a Swift object inside JSContext

Tags: javascript, swift

How do you modify a swift object passed as an argument to javascript executing in JSContext

I am playing with JSCore and Declared a testClass, I am making an instance of this class and then invoking a javascript function passing my instance as a parameter

```swift
import JavaScriptCore
import Foundation

let jsVM = JSVirtualMachine()
let jsContext = JSContext(virtualMachine: jsVM!)

@objc public protocol testJSExports : JSExport {
  var number: NSNumber? {get set}
}

@objc(testClass) class testClass : NSObject, testJSExports {
  public dynamic var number: NSNumber?
}

jsContext?.evaluateScript("""
  function modifyNumber(testInstance) {
  testInstance.number = -2
}
""")

let jsFunction = jsContext?.objectForKeyedSubscript("modifyNumber")

var testInstance = testClass()
testInstance.number = 11

jsFunction?.call(withArguments: [testInstance as Any])
print(testInstance.number) // would expect to print -2, actually prints 11
```

I expect the output of the last print statement to be -2 however the original value of 11 remains. Is it possible to modify a swift object inside javascript?

Comment: `modifyNumber` has a `testInstance` parameter, but writes to `testObject`.

Comment: nice catch! however the result is still the same, it is not being modified